# Grafana, Use of local variable in FLux query

Tags: grafana, flux-influxdb

beeing relativ new to Flux, I'm trying to make calculation on rows based on a value (tot) I get in amount.

```
> tot=from(bucket: "stat_tst")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop:v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>r._field == "speed" and r._value > 0.0)
  |> group()
  |> count()

from(bucket: "stat_tst")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop:v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>r._field == "speed" and r._value > 0.0)
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with _value: r._value / tot }))
```

and this is yielding me

```
invalid: type error @9:39-9:53: [A] is not Divisible
```

What am I doing wrong ? In advance thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, `tot` is a table. You need to extract scalar value like

```js
tot = from(bucket: "stat_tst")
  ...
  |> count()
  |> findColumn(fn: (key) => true, column: "_value")
```

See [Extract scalar values in Flux](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.2/query-data/flux/scalar-values/) for details.